# Where to save Gutenberg plugin data?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor, customization

I developed plugin where user can choose custom og:image.

[image]

I expect this to be part of response when I request data from REST API.

```
"meta": {
      "_title": "Custom Hello world Title!",
      "_description": "This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!",
      "_og_title": "Custom OG Hello world Title!",
      "_og_description": "Take a look at our first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!",
      "_og_image": "http:\/\/localhost:8069\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/11\/maxresdefault-1024x576.jpg"
},
```

Since I save selected img url as post meta "_og_image", I achieved it.

BUT! 
For correct displaying data in Gutenberg I need also somewhere to save the image Id. Then It will allow me to do not load large version of selected image but choose the small one. Also when I have the Id I can pre-select currently used image in media libray.

So to where am I supposed to save the Id? I find stupid to create another meta for this purpose.

Comment: You should only be saving the ID on the first place. Only get the URL when you’re outputting it on the front end.

Comment: Ok @JacobPeattie it is true. But I am developing decoupled front end. Specifically using Gatsby JS. So still I need more to have saved url than ID in my post meta.

Comment: So you know that you also need to save the ID, but your condition is that you don’t want to save the ID? You’re going to need to save another meta value. Honestly don’t know what you’re expecting here. To save the value you need to save the value. That simple.